# Radius of convergence of this power series

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, power-series

We're given the power series $$ \sum_1^\inf \frac{j!}{j^j}z^j$$

and are asked to find radius of convergence R. I know the formula $R=1/\limsup(a_n ^{1/n})$, which leads me to compute $\lim \frac{j!^{1/j}}{j}$, and then I'm stuck.

The solution manual calculates R by $1/\lim|\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}|$, but I can't figure out the motivation for that formula.

Comment: See for example [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700370/relationship-between-ratio-test-and-power-series-radius-of-convergence).

Answer (score 1):

Use Stirling's formula
$$n! \sim {n^n e^{-n}\over\sqrt{2\pi n}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) gives that, if $\{a_n\}$ is a positive sequence and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to L$, then
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n} = L, $$
too. You may also notice that by [Lagrange's inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) your series is related with the inverse function of $x\mapsto x\cdot e^x$, i.e. the [Lambert $W$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Thanks! now I remember reading about that result in an earlier chapter.