# Prove that $\lim \inf \dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\leq \lim \inf x_n^{1\over n} \leq \lim \sup x_n^{1\over n} \leq \lim \sup \dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}. $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

If $(x_n)$ is any sequence of positive real numbers, then $$\lim \inf \dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\leq \lim \inf x_n^{1\over n} \leq \lim \sup x_n^{1\over n} \leq \lim \sup \dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}. $$

I don't understand how am I suppose to use the hint nor what to do afterwards.

*Hint:* If $\lim \sup \dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}-\infty$, right hand inequality is obvious. So suppose $\lim \sup \dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=M$. Then $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}< M+\epsilon$ $\forall n\geq N$, i.e., $x_{n+k}\leq (M+\epsilon)^kx_n$ for all $k\geq 0$.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700370/relationship-between-ratio-test-and-power-series-radius-of-convergence)

Answer (score 3):

If 
$$
\limsup\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=M<\infty,
$$
then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$
\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\le M+\varepsilon, \quad n\ge N.
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{x_n}{x_N}=\frac{x_{N+1}}{x_N}\cdots\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n-1}}\le (M+\varepsilon)^{n-N},
$$
and hence
$$
x_n\le \frac{x_N}{(M+\varepsilon)^N}\cdot (M+\varepsilon)^n\quad\Rightarrow\quad
x_n^{1/n}\le \left(\frac{x_N}{(M+\varepsilon)^N}\right)^{1/n}\cdot (M+\varepsilon)
\to M+\varepsilon.
$$
Therefore
$$
\limsup x_n^{1/n}\le M+\varepsilon,\quad \text{for all $\varepsilon>0$.}
$$