# Prove for every $a_n>0$ if $\lim _{n\to \infty }\:\:\left(\sqrt[n]{a_n}\right)=L$ then $\lim _{n\to \infty }\:\:\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)=L$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove for every $a_n>0$ if $\lim _{n\to \infty }\:\:\left(\sqrt[n]{a_n}\right)=L$ then $\lim _{n\to \infty }\:\:\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)=L$  is true or false

> i know that's its true if $\lim _{n\to \infty }\:\:\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)=L$ then $\lim _{n\to \infty }\:\:\left(\sqrt[n]{a_n}\right)=L$

but in this case i think that this is false and my example is if $a_n=\sqrt[n]{n^n}$ then $\lim _{n\to \infty }\:\:\sqrt[n]{n^n}=\infty \:$ but $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)^n}{n^n}\right)=e$

is that correct?

Comment: That's not correct. A correct counter-example would be a sequence such that $(a_{+1}/a_n)\to\infty$ while $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ has a finite limit.

Comment: @Tom-Tom is there any example like that for $a_n>0$ ?

Comment: Your example is wrong. With $a_n = n^n$ you have $\sqrt[n]{a_n} = \sqrt[n]{n^n} \to \infty$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}  = \frac{\left(n+1\right)^{n+1}}{n^n} \to \infty$.

Comment: @MartinR yes i noticed that , i think that Spike Bughdaryan answer is correct because i tried alot to find example to prove it false but didn't find any

Comment: the question is prove if this statement is true or false

Comment: @D.Z.O: I misread your question. – The initial statement is wrong, consider the sequence $2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, \ldots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first statement does not hold. Consider the sequence $a_n = 1, 2, 1, 2, \ldots$. Then
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = 1$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} 
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ does not exist.

One always has (compare 
[Relationship Between Ratio Test and Power Series Radius of Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700370/relationship-between-ratio-test-and-power-series-radius-of-convergence) or [Limit of ${a_n}^{1/n}$ is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/limit-of-a-n1-n-is-equal-to-lim-n-to-infty-a-n1-a-n))
$$
 \liminf _{n \to \infty} 
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}
 \le \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}
 \le  \limsup_{n \to \infty} 
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
so that the existence of $\lim_{n \to \infty} 
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ implies the existence of 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ (with the same limit, which can
be finite, $+\infty$, or $-\infty$),
but not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

The theorem says that if both sequences has finite limit, then the two limits are equal.